# Substring function in XSLT behaves strange

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I'm searching for a **keywords** element that contains a value "by " and I want to extract the name that follows from it.

For example the **keywords** element can have a value "by John Doe" and I want to extract "John Doe", so I can use this name in another selection.

The simplified XML looks like this:

```
<article-set>

  <article id="blog-article">
    <title>Blog Article</title>
    <keywords>by John Doe</keywords> 
  </article>

  <article id="john-doe">
    <title>John Doe</title>
  </article>

</article-set>
```

An this is the related XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="article">
    <xsl:for-each select="keywords">  
        <xsl:if test="contains(current(), 'by ')">

                <xsl:value-of select="substring(current(), 3)"/>

                <xsl:value-of select="//article[title = 'John Doe']"/>

                <xsl:value-of select="//article[title = (substring(current(), 3))]"/>

        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

The results for each **value-of** are:

1. John Doe
2. Selects the article element I need as expected
3. **PROBLEM**: doesn't select anything.

So, since I am getting the expected results in the second hardcoded value-of, perhaps I am missing something fundamental about the substring function or in the given context?

Obs: I also tried setting a variable to *substring(current(), 3)* and referencing it instead of the hardcoded path ('John Doe') with no luck, I got the same behavior.

Does anyone have any ideea why this might happen?

Comment: Consider to post minimal but complete samples allowing us to reproduce the problem. I am afraid `</xsl:template match="article">` would not even be parsed by an XML parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index into an XPath string starts with 1 so given `by John Doe` I think you want `//article[title = substring(current(), 4)]`.

Comment: That was right on the money, thank you very much! There was an extra blank space I missed when outputting the value outside the selection.

I appreciate your inputs, I'll be more careful to post complete test cases next time!